# Pass database data to multiples views-Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a database with details of daily sales.

To query a database, I have a form in a view with parameters that will query as date of admission, client and others.

The result is shown in another view with the daily details of income, and below is a summary of the article do all entered.

The summary I wish to transfer to another view, try to view :: composer but only transfer the empty query (I saw it with debug bar). Just appeared an empty view.

How I can transfer data from the database without the latter view is empty?

The second html view is totaly diferent , only the data is the same.

Comment: Post your working code and then ask what do you want. It's really very hard to understand what you are talking about.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this correctly, you want to query a database in one view, and pass the details to another view?

Why not query the data in the second view instead? Pass the data from your first view by targetting your form to the second view. From there use `$value = Input::get('key')` to get the necessary values from your form, and query your database!

Comment: how pass the data to the next view, with a form? but the first view where data appears I will not have a form, the data appears as text.

Comment: Post whatever code you have already, I'm not able to understand exactly what you mean